# Tips for managing code when developing a parent theme framework

Tags: themes, customization, code, workflow

I have started work on an open source theme framework that pulls in lots of great code & resources from elsewhere. For example it uses:

- jQuery
- [Option Framework Theme](https://github.com/devinsays/options-framework-theme)
- [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

etc etc.

Most of these external projects are hosted on Github or SVN.

Rather than continually download and integrate the latest versions of these other libraries into my framework I am looking for a way to automate this process.

I would be prepared to change the way I work considerably to accomodate an automated work flow that ensures I am always up to date and not always downloading or duplicating files.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is [git submodules](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html):

> Git's submodule support allows a repository to contain, as a
>   subdirectory, a checkout of an external project.

PS: Always try to use the jQuery bundled with WordPress.

Answer (score 2):

Well use git.

With git you can `fork` or `clone` projects or blobs which keeps them tied into the original.

For example clone jquery onto you local dev folder where you want it:

```
// this will default to master origin
// should be cloned into a project sub-directory like /js
$ git clone git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git /js

//add the remote upstream
 git remote add upstream  git://github.com/jquery/jquery.git

// fetch changes from parent jquery and merge them with yours
 git fetch upstream
 git merge upstream/master
```

This is a simple example but git takes seconds to push/pull and merge large amounts of data around, and you can move into more advanced stuff like git sub-modules.

Make sure you use the proper folder structure and it's best (unless your using sub-modules) to have one repo to be pulling data into, git does not work very well with nested repo's.